# How to add headers in superagent GET request

Tags: node.js, http, get, superagent

Here is a basic code:

```
const superagent = require('superagent');

superagent.get('https://api.arabam.com/pp/step')
.query({ apikey: '_V85Kref7xGZHc1XRpUmOhDDd07zhZTOvUSIbJe_sSNHSDV79EjODA==' })
.end((err, res) => {
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }
  console.log(res.body.url);
  console.log(res.body.explanation);
});
```

But apikey is header rather than query. How do I send it as a header?

Edit:

I have tried using request module and it simply says that I'm unable to access it

```
var request = require("request");

request({
  uri: "https://api.arabam.com/pp/step",
  method: "GET",
  'Content-Type' : "application/json",
  apikey: "_V85Kref7xGZHc1XRpUmOhDDd07zhZTOvUSIbJe_sSNHSDV79EjODA=="
}, function(error, response, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

It says unauthorized to access

Answer (score 1):

From the [Setting header fields](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#setting-header-fields) doc, you should use

`request.set('apikey', '_V85Kref7xGZHc1XRpUmOhDDd07zhZTOvUSIbJe_sSNHSDV79EjODA==')`

to set the header field.